# rospack ends with "rosboost_cfg.rosboost_cfg.BoostError"

Tags: rospack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While I'm trying to build the stack someone made 2 years ago, I started having this error since a week ago and haven't been able to remove it.

```
% rospack libs-only-L --deps-only packageA
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/diamondback/ros/bin/rosboost-cfg", line 35, in <module>
    rosboost_cfg.main()
  File "/opt/ros/diamondback/ros/tools/rosboost_cfg/src/rosboost_cfg/rosboost_cfg.py", line 359, in main
    output = lflags(ver, options.lflags.split(','))
  File "/opt/ros/diamondback/ros/tools/rosboost_cfg/src/rosboost_cfg/rosboost_cfg.py", line 276, in lflags
    print >> s, lib_flags(ver, lib),
  File "/opt/ros/diamondback/ros/tools/rosboost_cfg/src/rosboost_cfg/rosboost_cfg.py", line 265, in lib_flags
    lib = find_lib(ver, name)
  File "/opt/ros/diamondback/ros/tools/rosboost_cfg/src/rosboost_cfg/rosboost_cfg.py", line 246, in find_lib
    raise BoostError('Could not locate library [%s] in lib directory [%s]'%(name, dir))
rosboost_cfg.rosboost_cfg.BoostError: 'Could not locate library [math] in lib directory [/usr/lib]'
[rospack] warning: got non-zero exit status from executing backquote expression "ret="-Wl,-rpath,/home/ros-user/Documents/Workspace_Eclipse/packageA/crowdnav_common/lib -L/home/ros-user/Documents/Workspace_Eclipse/packageA/crowdnav_common/lib -lcrowdnav_common `rosboost-cfg --lflags math,signals,thread`" && echo $ret" in [/home/ros-user/Documents/Workspace_Eclipse/packageA/crowdnav_common/manifest.xml]
[rospack] error in backquote expansion for packageA
```

I can't detect where this package designates the "math" library, nor from where rosboost_cfg.py is called (seems like rospack.cpp doesn't call it).

Env) Ubuntu 10.10, diamondback/electric (same under either distribution)

Thanks.

---

**Update** 9/9/2011)
In response to the suggestion, I checked libboost-math-dev which I found is already installed as follows:

```
/usr/share/doc/libboost-math1.42-dev
/usr/share/doc/libboost-math1.42.0
/usr/share/doc/libboost-math-dev
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/libboost-math1.42.0
```

But the error log indicates it searched /usr/lib. Any way to modify/add the search path? I looked at rosboost_cfg.py where I couldn't find one.

---

**Update** 9/9/2011 #2)

In /usr/lib, [many libboost_math* files are found](http://pastebin.com/tyU3xEtr), which seems to correspond to the files of libboost_math-dev (note that incl. underscore) that is [defined in ubuntu's web site](http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/amd64/libboost-math1.42-dev/filelist).

---

**Update** 9/13/2011)

Modifying rosboost_cfg.py as https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/attachment/ticket/3671/rosboost_cfg.py.20110912.diff bypassed the error. However, since I haven't regression tested, side effect might occur.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11155/rospack-ends-with-%22rosboost_cfg.rosboost_cfg.boosterror%22/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2011-09-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2011-09-09**:
@Brian Gerkey as the link of the pastebin I put shows, libboost_math files are there. Is it possibly because the rospack's option used is -libs-only-L so that that files starting with lower l are ignored? If that's the case, how can I configure to accept lower l files...

**Comment by [Brian Gerkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/8/brian-gerkey/) on 2011-09-09**:
Libraries gets installed to /usr/lib.  Check whether you have the boost math library: `ls /usr/lib/libboost_math*`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm able to replicate your problem (see below for more).  The first I would try is removing `math` from the call to `rosbuild_link_boost()` in the package's `CMakeLists.txt`.  Perhaps you don't really need boost.math.

The way to debug this is to call `rosboost-cfg` directly, e.g.:

```
rosboost-cfg --libs math,signals,thread
```

Or even more specifically:

```
rosboost-cfg --libs math
```

On both OSX and Ubuntu 10.04, the above query for the boost.math library fails.  It seems that the naming scheme on the boost.math library is different from the other boost libraries, causing `rosboost-cfg`'s pattern match not to work.  There's probably a patch to made to `rosboost-cfg`, around line 211.

---

Originally posted by [Brian Gerkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/8/brian-gerkey/) with karma: 2916 on 2011-09-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2011-09-13**:
@Brian Gerkey Modifying the code as you pointed out bypassed the error. I added the change in the body above, and also submitted a ticket (for the 1st time so not sure if I follow the tickt submission rule though) http://goo.gl/lgjbr . Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On my 64-bit Ubuntu (13.10), the boost libraries are installed in `/usr/lib/x86-64-linux-gnu`, so rosboost-cfg needs to be made aware of this by setting `ROS_BOOST_LIB_DIR_NAME` like this:

```
ROS_BOOST_LIB_DIR_NAME=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ rosboost-cfg --libs thread
```

and it is able to find the boost libraries again.
You can of course also set the environment variable, if you do not want to add the `ROS_BOOST_LIB_DIR_NAME` all the time:

```
export ROS_BOOST_LIB_DIR_NAME=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
rosboost-cfg --libs thread
```

---

Originally posted by [veger](https://answers.ros.org/users/11971/veger/) with karma: 43 on 2014-02-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3